# How to stitch schemas using apollo graphQL?

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js, apollo-federation

I am a java programmer learning graphQL. I have dataset as below sample where comment has postId, but post doestn't have comment information.

```
     comments
     {
        "postId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
        "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
        "body": "laudantium enim quasi"
      }

    post
      {
        "userid": 3,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Post 1"
      }
```

Using Apollo Federation

1. Can I have comment details in Post response?

   `{
     "data": {
     "posts": [
             {
            "userid": 3,
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Post 1"
            "comments":
               {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
                "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
                "body": "laudantium enim quasi"
                }
              }
             ]
           }`

   2. I need to basically use following algorithm

      - get all comments
      - Filter comments with given postId
      - collect all matching comments and return from resolver function

      Below is the post.js code

      ```
       type Post @key(fields: "id"){
           id: ID!
           userid: Int!
           title: String!
           comments: [Comment]
         }

         extend type Comment @key(fields: "id" ){
             id: ID! @external
         }

        const resolvers = {
          Post: {
              comments(post){
                return ( { __typename: "Post",  postId:post.id });
             }

         Query: {
              post: (root, { id }, { dataSources }) => dataSources.mvrpAPI.getAPost(id),
             posts: (root, args, { dataSources }) => dataSources.mvrpAPI.getAllPosts()}
      ```

With above resolver's comment method I am getting below error

```
  "message": "Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field
 \"Post.comments\".",
```

then I tried below resolver method and this cannot recognize mvrpAPI, even though it works in query section of resolvers

```
     async comments(post, {dataSources}){
      const allComments =  dataSources.mvrpAPI.getAllComments();;

      return allComments.postId.findAll(
        { __typename: "Post",  postId:post.id }
      );
    }
    }
```

Can someone help on how to write above mentioned logic (in point 2) in graphql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how I solved above issue

1. response.filter retuns an array and since I was looking for an array of comments with specific post id, just putting condition inside map function helped.
2. dataSources.mvrpAPI.getAllComments() gives Promise . To get real Object I  used "await" and since await can only be used from async function, I made comments function async.

   ```
   async comments(post, {postid}, {dataSources}){
        const response =  await dataSources.mvrpAPI.getAllComments();
          return response.filter(comment => comment.postId === post.id);
        }
     },
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring comments as a list on the Post schema, and on the resolver you are returning a single object

> return ( { __typename: "Post",  postId:post.id });

that's the reason for the "Expected Iterable" error.

I'm not familiar with that database api, but this shouldn't be hard with most api's.

In mongoose it would be something like

```
async (post,_, {model}) => model.Comment.find({postId: post.id})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gabriel. You are right that return ( { __typename: "Post", postId:post.id }); returns single object. I figured issue and posting solution in my comment below. Thanks again